# Как сделать маркеры в нумерованном списке жирным шрифтом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать маркеры `<li>` в нумерованном списке жирным шрифтом?

```html
<h2>Contents</h2>
<ol id="ol">
  <li>History</li>
  <ol type="1">
    <li>Development</li>
    <li>HTML versions timeline</li>
    <ol type="a">
      <li>HTML draft version timeline</li>
      <li>XHTML versions</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>
  <li>Markup</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Elements</li>
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Element examples</li>
      <li>Attributes</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Character and entity references</li>
    <li>Data types</li>
    <li>Document type declaration</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Semantic HTML</li>
  <li>Delivery</li>
  <ol>
    <li>HTTP</li>
    <li>HTML e-mail</li>
    <li>Naming conventions</li>
    <li>HTML Application</li>
  </ol>
  <li>HTML4 variations</li>
  <ol>
    <li>SGML-based versus XML-based HTML</li>
    <li>Transitional versus strict</li>
    <li>Frameset versus transitional</li>
    <li>Summary of specification versions</li>

  </ol>
  <li>HTML5 variants</li>
  <ol>
    <li>WHATWG HTML versus HTML5</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Hypertext features not in HTML</li>
  <li>WYSIWYG editors</li>
  <li>See also</li>
  <li>References</li>
  <li>External links</li>
</ol>
```

[image: это есть]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать псевдоэлемент `::marker`, хотя поддержки IE нет (но он Вам вряд ли уже нужен)

```css
li::marker {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Contents</h2>
<ol id="ol">
  <li>History</li>
  <ol type="1">
    <li>Development</li>
    <li>HTML versions timeline</li>
    <ol type="a">
      <li>HTML draft version timeline</li>
      <li>XHTML versions</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>
  <li>Markup</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Elements</li>
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Element examples</li>
      <li>Attributes</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Character and entity references</li>
    <li>Data types</li>
    <li>Document type declaration</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Semantic HTML</li>
  <li>Delivery</li>
  <ol>
    <li>HTTP</li>
    <li>HTML e-mail</li>
    <li>Naming conventions</li>
    <li>HTML Application</li>
  </ol>
  <li>HTML4 variations</li>
  <ol>
    <li>SGML-based versus XML-based HTML</li>
    <li>Transitional versus strict</li>
    <li>Frameset versus transitional</li>
    <li>Summary of specification versions</li>

  </ol>
  <li>HTML5 variants</li>
  <ol>
    <li>WHATWG HTML versus HTML5</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Hypertext features not in HTML</li>
  <li>WYSIWYG editors</li>
  <li>See also</li>
  <li>References</li>
  <li>External links</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Благодарю. То что искал.Требовалось его сделать так же черным цветом. Добавил "color: black;"